# How can I force Windows to remove a program?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I broke [Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET), and I can't remove it, and I do not have access to the command line.

How can I get Windows to uninstall this program?

Comment: You can't find a command line? What does that mean? Have you tried Start -> "Control Panel" -> "Add/Remove Programs" or "Programs and Features"?

Comment: Explain your question better.  What does "I can't find command line" mean?  Are you expecting a terminal-based uninstaller like you'd use in some Linux distros?

Comment: The only official way I know of to force windows to remove installed .msi's is to use msizap which is a command line utility.  There may be a third party software that is a frontend to this command, or performs its equivalent, but I don't know of one.  The alternative is to manually delete/revert any files and registry entries it has added which requires intimate knowledge of what the installer does.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall Paint.NET, which will re-add it to the Control Panel's Programs applet.  Then, if necessary, you can uninstall.  (The applet has different names depending on your Windows version,which you didn't state.)

Be sure to install the same version you had before--installing a new one might not work correctly with your system in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

> Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Add or Remove Programs" control panel applet.
>
> Revo Uninstaller is a much faster and more powerful alternative to "Windows Add or Remove Programs" applet! It has very powerful features to uninstall and remove programs.
>
> - No more stubborn programs
> - No more installation errors
> - No more upgrade problems
> - Remove programs easily
>
> With its advanced and fast algorithms, Revo Uninstaller Pro analyzes an application's data before uninstall and scans for remnants after the uninstall of a program. After the program's regular uninstaller runs, you can remove additional unnecessary files, folders and registry keys that are usually left over on your computer. Revo Uninstaller Pro offers you some simple, easy to use, but effective and powerful methods for uninstalling software like tracing the program during its installation.
>
> Revo Uninstaller Pro has a very powerful feature called Forced Uninstall. Forced Uninstall is the best solution when you have to remove stubborn programs, partially installed programs, partially uninstalled programs, and programs not listed as installed at all!
>
> To remove a program completely, and without leaving a trace, you can monitor all system changes made during its installation, and then use that information to uninstall it with one click only – simple and easy!